# Chilkat 9.5.0: Error installing in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, chilkat

I'm trying to install Chilkat 9.5 on Windows Server 2003 but it shows me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please, do paste your error message as a codeblock instead of an image. Or, at least, embed the image here so it's easier to follow the problem along.

Comment: Hi Phillip, please click on [https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i8CD.png]. Well, a "Windows Installer" window opens when I'm trying to install Chilkat 9.5 on Windows Server 2003. This windows asks for parameters.

Comment: Type the text in that window into a codeblock.

Comment: Hi Philippe. Please, see message original. I accepted your suggestion.